# Y a-t-il quelqu'un qui prononce "sac" différemment de "sacs" (= "sâc")?

Tags: prononciation, pluriel, phonétique, accents-régionaux

J'ai appris récemment quelque chose qui m'a choqué. Selon le livre *[An Oral System of Imparting the French Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=dSYBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=french%20words%20ending%20in%20aigne&source=bl&ots=LUjvBdoPfL&sig=hK8i4LQ7d1yhiBcKsTwsnNEeOnU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_lcXgnozRAhWpiFQKHUi8CTEQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=french%20words%20ending%20in%20aigne&f=false),* par L. A. Audigier, il y a une différence en français entre la prononciation de *sac* et *sacs.* Aussi entre *lac, lacs*; *sel, sels*; *pot, pots* (p. 24).

Je connaissais déjà la différence de longueur dans certain accents (par exemple, l'accent belge ou québécois) entre les voyelles de "tache" et "tâche", ou (pour les Belges) la différence entre des mots comme "parlé" et "parlée". Je sais aussi que pour beaucoup, ces distinctions n'existent plus.

Mais je ne savais pas qu'il pouvait y avoir une différence comme ça entre le singulier et le pluriel.

Je sais que ce livre est très vieux. Y a-t-il encore quelqu'un qui fait la distinction entre la prononciation de "sac" et "sacs"?

---

(in English)

Recently, I learned something that shocked me. According to the book *[An Oral System of Imparting the French Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=dSYBAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA26&lpg=PA26&dq=french%20words%20ending%20in%20aigne&source=bl&ots=LUjvBdoPfL&sig=hK8i4LQ7d1yhiBcKsTwsnNEeOnU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_lcXgnozRAhWpiFQKHUi8CTEQ6AEILzAE#v=onepage&q=french%20words%20ending%20in%20aigne&f=false),* by L. A. Audigier, there is a difference in French between the pronunciation of *sac* and *sacs*. The same goes for *lac, lacs; sel, sels; pot, pots* (p. 24).

I already knew about the difference of length in certain accents (for example, a Belgian or Quebec accent) between the vowels of "tache" and "tâche", or (for the Belgians) the difference between words like "parlé" and "parlée". I also know that for many people, these distinctions no longer exist.

But I never know that there could be a difference like this between the singular and the plural.

I know this book is very old. Does anyone today still distinguish the pronunciation of "sac" and "sacs"?

---

(Je serais heureux de recevoir des réponses dans la langue de votre choix.)

Comment: En temps que locuteur français, je ne fais pas cette distinction pour les mots indiqués et je n'ai pas souvenir de l'avoir jamais entendue. Par contre, je fais bien la différence entre « tache » et « tâche »

Comment: @Toto Quelle différence de prononciation fais-tu entre *tache* et *tâche* ? Merci.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps: Comme indiqué dans wikipedia :  `[taʃ]` pour le premier et `[tɑʃ]` pour le deuxième (un peu plus long et ouvert).

Comment: @Toto Merci, et tu fais vraiment la distinction en le disant ? Je ne crois pas avoir jamais constaté une différence.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps: Oui,sinon le sens d'une phrase peut être complètement différent. Dans un autre ordre d'idée je fais la différence entre « Paul » et « Paule ».

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Plus précisément une monophtongue prononcée pendant le double de sa durée au singulier ([sak] → [sa:k]) PS: il n'y a plus de diphtongues en français.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour la précision et je ne connaissais pas le mot monophtongue ! p.s. : la [diphtonguaison](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=diphtongue&T3.x=0&T3.y=0) est _relativement fréquente_ en français parlé au Québec, et donc c'était simplement une association courante pour moi, la durée plus longue etc.

Comment: @Tunedéroberas. Ah oui, c'est vrai, il y a des diphtongues en français du Québec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non, cette différence n'existe dans aucune variante du français contemporain. Si tant est qu'elle ait réellement existé, elle a disparu au cours du 18e siècle.

Dans son [Traité de la prosodie française](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50813j/f2.image) (1737) l'abbé Olivet indique à de nombreuses reprises que certains mots monosyllabiques voient leur « quantité » (longueur de la syllabe) passer de brève au singulier à longue au pluriel.

Dans son [Traité de prononciation](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k64732459/f7.image) (1836), Sophie Dupuis écrit, commentant l'ouvrage précédent :

> Ici certainement la vue trompe l'oreille, et le préjugé la raison, car il est impossible de trouver la moindre différence entre *le sac, les sacs, le sel, les sels, le pot, les pots* à moins que la prononciation n'ait subi de grands changements.

Cette distinction était donc déjà inexistante il y a presque deux siècles.

Answer (score 3):

Parlant le français depuis toujours et ayant vécu dans différentes régions avec des gens utilisant des accents plus ou moins différents et prononcés, je n'ai jamais entendu quelqu'un prononcer différemment les mots *sac* et *sacs*.

Les consonnes finales étaient notamment prononcées en latin. Néanmoins, avec l'apparition de l'ancien français, la prononciation de ces consonnes a fini par disparaître avec le temps. Comme expliqué [dans ce lien](http://ebooks.grsu.by/history_french_lang/l-ancien-fran-ais-les-changements-phonetiques.htm) expliquant les changements apportés par l'ancien français sur le latin:

> Toutes les consonnes finales continuent à s’effacer.
>
> C’est surtout la chute des consonnes finales -s et -t qui a de grosses conséquences morphologiques, car:
>
> – elle a contribué à l’écroulement  de l’ancienne déclinaison: C. S. murs =  C. R. mur;
>
> – elle a amené l’effacement du pluriel des noms:  Sing. garçon = Plur.  garçons;
>
> – elle a favorisé l’unification du présent au singulier: (tu) chantes = (il) chante.
>
> En graphie s se conserve jusqu’à nos jours, **tandis que dans la prononciation il commence à disparaître dès le XIIIe s**.
>
> La finale -t ne se prononce plus à partir du XII e s.: (il) chante(t).

La différence de prononciation entre *sac* et *sacs* n'est donc plus vraiment d'actualité aujourd'hui.

Comment: Merci. Je suppose que même selon Audigier, on prononcerait "garçon" et "garçons" et "chante" et "chantes" de façon identique. Mais "murs" et "mur", non.

Comment: La question ne porte pas sur la (non) prononciation du *s* final, qui n'est pas remise en cause dans l'ouvrage cité, mais sur l'allongement supposé de la voyelle de certains mots monosyllabiques au pluriel.